# accessing children of divs using tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following divs..

```
 <div class="color-picker-preview-control">
            <div class="color-picker-color-preview"></div>
            <div class="color-picker-hex-wrap">
                <label>{{colorpicker-dialog-hex-or-rgb-label}}</label>
                <input type="text" class="color-picker-color-hex">
            </div>
            <div class="eye-dropper">
                <div class="eye-dropper-button" title="{{colorpicker-dialog-eyedropper-title}}"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="color-picker-gradient-wrap">
            <div class="color-picker-sl-field">
                <canvas class="color-picker-sl-gradient"></canvas>
                <canvas class="color-picker-sl-back hide"></canvas>
                <div class="color-field-handle sl-handle"><div class="dot"></div></div>
            </div>

            <div class="color-picker-slider">
                <canvas class="color-picker-gradient hue-gradient"></canvas>
                <div class="color-picker-handle hue-handle" data-part="hue"><div class="dot"></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I would like to access the children of divs and the next div using tabbing. How can I do this using jquery or HTML?

Comment: What do u mean with tabbing?

Comment: accessing elements using TAB keyboard key

Comment: In general - depending on the browser and the OS - input fields, radio butons,  buttons aso.  can normally be accessed via tab /shift tab in plain HTML. To access divs (why should I access divs?) need javascript or css disguising above elements to enable access via tabs.

Comment: you don't do that using `jquery` you need to add [tabIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex).